# Website not secure when using www.example.com but working fine as example.com

Tags: https, apache2, amazon-route53

I have a website published on AWS and I used [Lets Encrypt](https://letsencrypt.org) for its `SSL` certificate. In my apache configuration I added the domain as:

```
ServerAlias example.com *.example.com
```

On AWS route 53 I added a `CNAME` and redirected the `www.example.com` to `example.com`.

The issue is that website is secure when I do `example.com` but not with `www.example.com`

Comment: CNAME is not a redirection. Configure the redirection in your web server, instead of doing it in DNS.

Comment: I saw the `CNAME` solution online. But I wrote the `RewriteRule` in apache configuration as well